# How do I respond to the error message after running npm run dev?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I would like to create a local development environment using the template at the following URL. I am trying to follow the steps. When I run npm run dev, I get an error. I do not know what to do in such a case. Can someone please help me?

URL: https://github.com/puikinsh/Adminator-admin-dashboard

```
[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.                                    │└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ 
│  - options has an unknown property 'stats'. These properties are valid:                                                                                              │┌─Operation────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
│    object  allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?,   ││                                                      │ 
│  onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, setupExitSignals?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer?
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path'); 
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin'); 
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); 
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin'); 
const { loader } = require('mini-css-extract-plugin'); 

module.exports = { 
  entry:'./src/javascripts/main.js', 
  output: { path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'), 
  filename: 'javascripts/main.js' },
  module: { 
    rules:[ 
      { test:/\.css/, 
        use:[ { loader:MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, }, { loader:'css-loader', }]
      }, 
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)/,
        type: 'asset/resource', 
        generator: { filename: 'images/[name][ext]', }, 
        use:[ 
          { loader: 'file-loader',
            options:{ esModule:false, 
            name:'images/[name].[ext]'
          }]
       },
       { test: /\.pug/, 
         use: [
           { loader:'html-loader', }, 
           { loader:'pug-html-loader' }
           ]
        }]
       },
  plugins: [ 
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename:'./stylesheets/main.css' }), 
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/templates/index.html' }), 
    new CleanWebpackPlugin() 
    ]},
```

devServer.js

```js
// ---------------------
// @Loading Dependencies
// ---------------------

const
  manifest = require('./manifest');


// ------------------
// @DevServer Configs
// ------------------

/**
 * [1] : To enable local network testing
 */

const devServer = {
  contentBase        : manifest.IS_PRODUCTION ? manifest.paths.build : manifest.paths.src,
  historyApiFallback : true,
  port               : manifest.IS_PRODUCTION ? 3001 : 3000,
  compress           : manifest.IS_PRODUCTION,
  inline             : !manifest.IS_PRODUCTION,
  watchContentBase: true,
  hot                : !manifest.IS_PRODUCTION,
  host               : '0.0.0.0',
  disableHostCheck   : true, // [1]
  overlay            : true,
  stats: {
    assets     : true,
    children   : false,
    chunks     : false,
    hash       : false,
    modules    : false,
    publicPath : false,
    timings    : true,
    version    : false,
    warnings   : true,
    colors     : true,
  },
};


// -----------------
// @Exporting Module
// -----------------

module.exports = devServer;
```

Comment: const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const { loader } = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry:'./src/javascripts/main.js',
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'javascripts/main.js'
    },

Comment: module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.css/,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader:MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    {
                        loader:'css-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },

Comment: {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'images/[name][ext]',
                },
                use:[ 
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options:{
                            esModule:false,
                            name:'images/[name].[ext]',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },

Comment: {
                test: /\.pug/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader:'html-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader:'pug-html-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    
    plugins:[
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename:'./stylesheets/main.css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/templates/index.html',
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
}

Comment: The four posts above are the contents of webpack.config.js.
I've divided them into four posts because of the amount of text.
If you put them in one file, starting with the top post
webpack.config.js is the result.

Answer (score 0):

The message is quite self-explanatory. Your config file is invalid, because you use unknown keys in your webpack object (here `stats`). Please post your entire webpack config, so people can check the error.

Comment: I pasted in the entire contents of webback.config.js.
Are you sure?

Comment: I've edited your post in order to provide a properly formatted config. I don't see any `stats` here. Are you sure the config is complete?

Comment: Thank you for integrating the source.
It looks like you're missing about four closing parentheses.
Other than that, the source is the same as the webpack.config.js source found here.